# Problemas varios con Github para visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, git, github

Tengo un proyecto personal con el que estoy usando github para visual studio con el VS 2015 community. No hay nadie más trabajando en esto, y siempre trabajo desde el mismo ordenador.

Para ahorrar tiempo, la cuestión es que en ahora en visual studio me aparece la solución de una manera totalmente diferente a como está en el repositorio remoto, en github. VS cree que está así y no hay manera de convencerlo de otra cosa, he hecho `fetch`, `pull` y lo que se me ha ocurrido, pero sinceramente ya no se me ocurre que más hacer, será por que soy un amateur y me faltan conocimientos, no sé, pero estoy totalmente perdido ahora mismo.

**¿Debería directamente clonar el repositorio remoto en otro nuevo local y ponerme a trabajar con el nuevo?**

Por si acaso alguien me da otra solución, ahora explico cómo llegué hasta donde estoy.

Hace unos días terminé con una rama e hice un `merge` con la rama master desde el mismo visual studio. Tras resolver todos los conflictos (muchos), voy a revisar si todo salió bien y me encuentro con que visual studio ha marcado varios ficheros (que ni siquiera dieron conflicto cuando hice el `merge`) con un icono como un triángulo amarillo y a otros, además del triángulo, les ha puesto a la izquierda un signo "-" en rojo, apareciendo como ignorados si dejo el ratón encima de ellos.

Me voy a la página de github a revisar qué ha pasado en el remoto y veo que efectivamente los marcados en amarillo no están en la rama master: por alguna razón que no comprendo no se copiaron los archivos cuando hice `merge` (aún cuando aparecen con ese icono que decía antes no se pueden abrir), pero sí estaban y siguen estando en la rama original. Sin embargo, los marcados en rojos sí están en su sitio en el remoto aunque VS diga que no están.
Abro el explorador de archivos y veo que efectivamente los marcados en amarillo no están en la rama master... ¡pero los marcados en rojo están en otra carpeta que ni siquiera aparece en visual studio!

Intento dar marcha atrás al merge y volverlo a hacer, con los mismos resultados. Después hago un cambio menor en la rama original, para que VS reconozca que ha habido cambios, y vuelvo a hacer otro merge a ver si esta vez "ve" los archivos y los copia, nada tampoco. Como en el remoto sí existen los arhivos que estaban en rojo y están bien, intento sobreescribir el local haciendo:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull
```

Reviso en el explorador de archivos y efectivamente ahora todo está igual que en el remoto, abro la solución en el VS y el mismo visual studio vuelve a cambiar los ficheros por su propia cuenta a como él cree que deberían estar (mal, con los archivos ignorados, los otros en una carpeta diferente, etc.).
Intento añadir los archivos "perdidos" vía "Add existing item". Básicamente voy a la rama original, copio los archivos a otra carpeta del disco duro, vuelvo al master y los añado donde deberían estar. Hago un `commit` para que los archivos suban al remoto y todo ok en el remoto, pero ahora VS me dice que todavía tengo cambios pendientes (sí, justo despues de hacer `commit` y `push` me dice que hay cambios pendientes).
Me doy por vencido y revierto todos los cambios hasta el primer merge, para intentar otra solución desde el principio, y aquí es cuando VS se vuelve definitivamente loco, desaparecen carpetas y proyectos enteros de la solución, otros archivos se revierten a un estado en el que no estaban hace meses y otros se quedan como deberían estar... un caos total.
Mientras, el repositorio remoto está perfecto, como debería estar antes de ese primer `merge` original.

Por eso dije antes lo de clonar el remoto en uno nuevo local y seguir desde ahí, por que el remoto está perfecto, y aunque todavía no sé por qué aquellos archivos no se copiaron en el primer `merge`, siempre podría hacer la trampa de añadirlos vía "Add existing item" otra vez.

**Edit:**
He clonado el repositorio desde consola como me recomendaron en los comentarios. Una vez clonado, con el explorador de windows veo que los archivos existen localmente, igual que en el repositorio remoto, pero VS no los ve, incluso he borrado el repositorio local junto a la carpeta `.git` y he vuelto a clonar.
Lo único que se me ocurre es que el archivo `.sln` se haya quedado mal (no logro entender por qué razón) y VS crea que todos esos archivos no pertenecen a la solución, por que estar, están ahí.
Lo más curioso es que en la otra rama la solución se abre perfectamente, con todos los archivos y carpetas incluidos, he intentado hacer `merge` de nuevo, pero sigue diciéndome que no hay cambios (por supuesto).
¿Debería incluir todos los archivos y carpetas en la solución "a mano", arrastrándolos desde el explorador?
Estoy pensando, **¿quizá sería mejor convertir la rama que está bien en la `master`, y borrar la actual master que está patas arriba?**

**Edit2:**
A petición de @NaCl en los comentarios pego el `.gitignore`:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# DNX
project.lock.json
artifacts/

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
## TODO: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your
## web deploy settings but do note that will include unencrypted
## passwords
#*.pubxml

*.publishproj

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!*.[Cc]ache/

# Others
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/
orleans.codegen.cs

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
# *.mdf
# *.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
_Pvt_Extensions/
ModelManifest.xml
```

Y el `git-status`:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Nox, te comento. A veces VS 2015 como manejador de ramas no es muy efectivo que digamos. Si los problemas persisten deberías utilizar los comandos via consola con Git CMD.  Y luego ve como quedaron los archivos en VS 2015.

Comment: El problema es que lo que hago desde la consola VS lo deshace en cuanto abro el proyecto, básicamente hace lo que le da la gana. Por ejemplo los merge los hice desde VS, pero como decía en la pregunta, el fetch y el reset los hice desde la consola, confirmé que los archivos estaban físicamente en el disco duro, y después el VS los borró. Es como si VS tuviera guardado el repositorio en algún lado independiente de Github, y cada vez que lo abro, él mismo, por su propia cuenta, devuelve el repositorio a como él cree que debería estar, sin confirmar con github o con el usuario.

Comment: Recuerda que hay una repositorio local que push contra uno remoto

Comment: Si ya clonaste el repositorio desde el `remote`, recuerda hacer siempre `git push` para sincronizar los cambios en el `remote`.

Comment: @ctm002 Sí, pero es que el VS está cambiando el repositorio local por su propia cuenta, es decir, yo hago un fetch por consola, el repositorio local se actualiza con el remoto y lo confirmo con el explorador de archivos de windows, todo bien. Después abro el proyecto con VS... y VS automáticamente hace sus propios cambios con el repositorio local, borra, crea y sobreescribe archivos dejando el local diferente a como está el remoto. Es decir, VS y github están descoordinados, comparten la carpeta pero con archivos diferentes. Github lo lleva bien, VS me hace un caos terrible con los archivos.

Comment: @NaCl No lo he clonado todavía, no, por eso vine aquí, no sé qué debo hacer, si clonarlo en otra carpeta y seguir con esa nueva o qué.

Comment: Si el proyecto está en github, deberías clonarlo directamente en `git-bash`, así tendrás el repositorio configurado para hacer `push` a `remote` sin mucho problema, de esa forma no debería haber problema con VS.

Comment: En VS igual hay un botón para sincronizar los cambios, pero prefiero hacer `git add . && git commit -m "Mensaje" && git push` en el terminal, así me aseguro que mis cambios estan sincronizados.

Comment: Confirmo lo que dice @NaCI, Corta por lo sano.

Comment: @NaCl ¿Con "clonarlo en `git-bash` " te refieres a hacerlo por la consola, por el git shell? Perdona, a veces me pierdo con tanta terminología... En cuanto al botón de sincronizar del VS: si te refieres al `Sync` del `Team Explorer`, ya lo he intentado y se lo pasa por el ****, el VS está empeñado en que su versión del repositorio es la buena y según él, no hay cambios, así que al darle a sincronizar, no hace nada de nada. En cualquier caso, si el `bash` es lo mismo que el `shell` (voy a buscarlo yo por mi cuenta también ;), lo intentaré en cuanto pueda y volveré por aquí a informar. Gracias.

Comment: Sí, me refiero al terminal que trae git, tomas el link que GitHub te ofrece para clonar el repositorio y haces `git clone`.

Comment: @NaCl He intentado clonar y he incluido los resultados en la pregunta con un edit.

Comment: Nox, algo importante, ¿Cuál es el cwd donde te encuentras? ¿Tiene `.gitignore` tu proyecto? ¿Podrías mostrarnos el resultado de la consola de `git-status` y de los comandos que intentas? Creo que sé cuál es tu problema.

Comment: @NaCl Recibido. Voy a intentar poner el ignore y el status en la pregunta.

Comment: Vamos a evitar el extenso debate en comentarios e ir al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) cuando puedas, así te pregunto mejor los detalles.

Comment: recomendaria realie el clone del repositorio en una nueva carpeta a ver si sigue sucediendo lo que mencionas, tambien podrias evaluar usar la integracion https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart  la cual la puede que venga habilitada sino la instalas desde las extensiones https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.GitHubExtensionforVisualStudio o lo puedes descargar https://visualstudio.github.com/  de esta forma no necesitas usar la linea de comando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luego de tanta caña y platica que dimos en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60834/sala-para-nox-y-nacl)<sup>1</sup> a ensayo y error sobre lo que se podía hacer en el repositorio, quedamos en que la mejor solución *(Por el momento)* sería re-inicializar el repositorio, se hizo de la siguiente forma:

1. Se descarga la rama más actualizada del proyecto *(Esa que tiene los cambios funcionales más recientes)*. *Ojo, no clonar, sino descargar.*
2. Crear un nuevo repositorio en el servidor de Git de su preferencia y clonar el mismo en el directorio deseado *(Diferente del directorio con problemas)*.
3. Para volverlo genérico, limpiamos la solución de cualquier tipo de binario o datos personales del usuario y se creó el siguiente `.gitignore`:

   ```
   [bB]in 
   [oO]bj 
   *.pdb 
   *.exe 
   *.json 
   .vs
   # Agregar cualquier otra cosa debajo.
   ```
4. Al final de todo, de haber verificado que todo compilaba, funcionaba y estaba listo para volver al `remote`, se decidió realizar:

   ```
   $ git add .
   $ git commit -m "Mensaje"
   $ git push
   ```

Al final de todo esto, se pudo lograr sincronizar todo el contenido del repositorio y VS los podía visualizar.

La decisión final adoptada fue no dejar que VS sincronizara los cambios con su integracion con git y utilizar los comandos del terminal para realizar todo lo necesario.

<sup>1</sup>: Link estará disponible por los proximos días, pasado ese lapso voy a eliminar la referencia a la sala de chat.